# Apache redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains example.com and example.net using the same .htaccess file in `public_html` directory. I want any valid url like `example.net/valid-url` to redirect to `example.com/valid-url`.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However the redirect is happening (with above code) to `example.com` not,

`example.com/valid-url`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.